# How to add a class instance from user input in python?

Tags: python

```
class Student(object):
    def __init__(self, name, chinese = 0, math = 0, english = 0):
        self.name = name
        self.chinese = chinese
        self.math = math
        self.english = english
        self.total = self.chinese + self.math + self.english
        Student.list.append(name)'
```

I'm trying to write a grade management system, all the student's score are stored in classes of their name. How can I add new instances to the class Student based on user input?

```
    name = raw_input("Please input the student's name:")
    chinese = input("Please input Chinese score:")
    math = input("Please input Math score:")
    english = input("Please input English score:")
    name = Student(name, chinese, math, english)
    # eval(name)
    # name = Student(name, chinese, math, english)
```

I've tried with these method but nothing works out.

Comment: What is `new_student`?

Comment: Those last two lines of code make very little sense, as does the question itself - "add new instances" to where??? Also, why are you posting your commented-out code as part of the question?

Comment: *What* doesn't work?

Comment: @AndrewL. `list` is a class-level object.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pprint
class Student():
#blah blah blah

if __name__ == "__main__":
    list_of_students = []
    while True:
        if raw_input("Add student? (y/n)") == "n":
            break
        # ask your questions here
        list_of_students.append( Student( # student data ) )
    for student in list_of_students:
        pprint.pprint(student.__dict__)
```

Comment: sutudent??? BTW, I'd check on the user input being equal to `'y'` before appending a new student.

Comment: meh, preferences ... depends if you're used to coding early returns or single return functions ... if the user just hits enter because they have 100 students to enter my way may be preferred ... but again, preference and use case

Comment: also, a sutudent is like a yute :P

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it the following way. :

```
from collections import defaultdict
class Student:

    def __init__(self, name=None, chinese=None, math=None, english=None):
        self.student_info = defaultdict(list)
        if name is not None:
            self.student_info['name'].append(name)
            self.student_info['chinese'].append(chinese)
            self.student_info['math'].append(math)
            self.student_info['english'].append(english)

    def add_student(self, name, chinese, math, english):
        if name is not None:
            self.student_info['name'].append(name)
            self.student_info['chinese'].append(chinese)
            self.student_info['math'].append(math)
            self.student_info['english'].append(english)
        return None
```

In your original question's code, there is no add method (just one constructor). Hence you cannot add any new student's information to the object.